# How to print object notation from variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, printing

I have a question about using variables with object notations. Let's say I have the following code:

```
let anObject = {
    name: 'Joaquin',
    age: 27,
    occupation: 'software developer',
    interests: ['walking', 'Arduino', 'working']
}
let print = 'interests[0]';
console.log(anObject.interests[0]); //prints the result
console.log(anObject.print); //prints undefined
```

If I log `anObject.interests[0]` it prints the expected result. But when I store `interests[0]` in a variable and print it again it doesn't.

How can we overcome this problem and why is it not printing the expected result?

Comment: print is a string "interest[0]", it does not retrieve a variable. Try with interests[0] with no quotes.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini: `Uncaught ReferenceError: interest is not defined`

Comment: Obviously: anObject.interests[0]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are a few examples to better understand what is going on and how to make it work:

```js
let anObject = {
    name: 'Joaquin',
    age: 27,
    occupation: 'software developer',
    interests: ['walking', 'Arduino', 'working'],
    'interests[0]': 'Hello SO !'
}

// As expected
console.log(anObject.interests[0]); //prints 'walking'

// Here you try to access the property named 'interests[0]'
let print = 'interests[0]';
console.log(anObject[print]); //prints 'Hello SO !'

// You can use eval and passing the entire expression to evaluate (Not recommended)
console.log(eval('anObject.' + 'interests[1]'));

// Better solution using Lodash
console.log(_.get(anObject, 'interests[1]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sure, `eval` "works", but don't ___ever___ suggest that as a valid solution. And using a library for something as basic as object access isn't "better".

Comment: Added Not recommended. Based on OP's problem it could be the only solution

Comment: It's not the only solution. It's relatively trivial to write a proper parser for those strings.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: The question was how to access a property based on a string that could be something like `'interests[0]'`. Not how to access that property directly. Also writing a "parser for those strings" is not "relatively trivial" to me.

Comment: That it isn't easy _for you_ doesn't mean it's not easy.

Comment: That's entirely true actually

Answer (score 0):

That's just not how JavaScript object access works.

`anObject.print` is looking for a `print` property on the `anObject` object.
It has *nothing* to do with your `print` *variable*.

The only wat JavaScript natively supports object access using strings, is by using individual property keys, like:

```
console.log(anObject['interests'][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
anObject
```

doesn't have a print key attached to the object. You are assigning a simple string to the variable that has nothing to do with the object.

A possible solution would be to do:

```
let print = anObject.interests[0]
console.log(print)
```

I have no idea what you're doing so please elaborate so I can provide additional help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with native JavaScript only. The only case it works is if your string of properties only contains one prop, and not `prop[0]`. And reading the prop can not be done by dot notation. You have to use:

```
obj[propString]
```

The lib lodash has the function `_.get()` that can do this if you need it!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a property is accessed in javascript object it is stringified. Javascript evaluates anObject.print as a property in anObject which doesn't exist and hence prints undefined. To get the desired result make the following correction.

```
    let anObject = {
        name: 'Joaquin',
        age: 27,
        occupation: 'software developer',
        interests: ['walking', 'Arduino', 'working']
    }
    let print = 'interests';
    console.log(anObject.interests[0]); //prints the result
    console.log(anObject[print][0]); //prints the result i.e. walking
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript we can access with:
 - dot notation
 - square brackets

But only second case allows to access properties dynamically but you can't just specify directly key with index `interests[0]`. You have to pass the key which return the array object and then you will access particular index which you want to get:

```js
let anObject = {
    name: 'Joaquin',
    age: 27,
    occupation: 'software developer',
    interests: ['walking', 'Arduino', 'working']
}
let print = 'interests';
let i = 0;
let print2 = 'age'
console.log(anObject.interests[0]); //prints the result
console.log(anObject[print]); // prints array object
console.log(anObject[print][i]); // print first value of array object
console.log(anObject[print2])
```